# Change concatenation separator in unlist

Tags: r

I have a list of lists that I want to unlist. My problem is that some names contains a `.`. How can I prevent unlist from using a `.` as a separator ? I then want to use `tstrsplit` to build a table.

```
library('data.table')

# without names with a . in the list everything is ok
to_unlist <- list('a1' = list('b' = 1, 'c' = 2), 
                  'a2' = list('b' = 3, 'c' = 4),
                  'a3' = list('b' = 5, 'c' = 6))
to_unlist <- unlist(to_unlist)
table <- data.table(names = names(to_unlist), value = to_unlist)
table[, c('V1', 'V2') := tstrsplit(names, ".", fixed = TRUE)]

# with a name containing a .
to_unlist <- list('a1' = list('b' = 1, 'c' = 2), 
                  'a2' = list('b' = 3, 'c' = 4),
                  'a3' = list('b.d' = 5, 'c' = 6))
to_unlist <- unlist(to_unlist)
table <- data.table(names = names(to_unlist), value = to_unlist)
# This gives an error
table[, c('V1', 'V2') := tstrsplit(names, ".", fixed = TRUE)]
# proper output should be
     names value V1  V2
1:   a1.b     1 a1   b
2:   a1.c     2 a1   c
3:   a2.b     3 a2   b
4:   a2.c     4 a2   c
5: a3.b.d     5 a3 b.d
6:   a3.c     6 a3   c
```

Line 5 is the problem, I want to keep the value of `b.d` but since I split on `.` I cannot do that.

How can I tell `unlist` to use a different separator than `.`? Or how can I change the names with a `.` in the list (my actual list comes from a json string and it is quite a long nested list)

I edited the question I hope it is more clear now.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is.  Both of the examples are working fine for me.  It would be good have an expected output

Comment: Did you meant `table <- data.table(names = sub("[.]", "_", names(to_unlist)), value = to_unlist)` and then use `table[, c('V1', 'V2') := tstrsplit(names, "_", fixed = TRUE)]`

Comment: Also, you can create the dataset with `melt` i.e. `melt(to_unlist)` before `unlist`ing and convert to `data.table`

Comment: using melt directly solves my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the `.` to `_` after `unlist`ing using `sub`, then specify the sep as `_` in `tstrsplit`

```
table <- data.table(names = sub("[.]", "_", names(to_unlist)), value = to_unlist)
table[, c('V1', 'V2') := tstrsplit(names, "_", fixed = TRUE)]
```

---

Or another option would be `melt` which directly converts the `list` in to `data.frame`

```
as.data.table(melt(to_unlist))
```